# Java stops before reaching end of loop without an error

Tags: java, netbeans

I have an loop that prints a number sequentially up to 200. However, java is stopping in the middle of the loop with no output that would suggest an error.

```
class TestContinuousRun {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int i=0;
    try {
        while(i<200){
            System.out.println(i++);
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I have tried compiling using javac from command line from a simple .java file as above.I have also tried using the Netbeans IDE and debugging. I have even tried compiling from Netbeans and running from command line. But no success.

I have also been checking, but it always runs for a different period of time, some times 5 minutes and some times less than a minute.

Any clue on what may be an issue? 
Or how could I start debugging with no information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess would be something is calling System.exit which would exit without causing an error. You could just use Find on the project to search the source for System.exit(0) or put a break point on System.exit.

Debug -> New Breakpoint, Debugger : Java, Breakpoint Type: Method, Class: java.lang.System, Uncheck All Methods Checkbox, Method: exit

[image]

Comment: Didnt know about this feature, thanks! I did try it out but the debug still exits without catching on this breakpoint.

Answer (score 1):

I tried the same code and it works properly with no issues and prints from 1 to 200

public class TestA {

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    int i=0;
    try {
        while(i<200){
            System.out.println(++i);

            Thread.sleep(50);
        } 
    }catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}